# "Unresolved reference" of a view's id from fragment layout in onViewCreated method

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-fragments

I am learning from a book written in 2018 in Android Studio 3 while mine is Android Studio 4. The langage is Kotlin. 
So I encounter some troubles of implementation.

I tried to follow the binding with current rules proposed in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#fragments)

```
package com.example.ch14fragmentsbooks

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.example.ch14fragmentsbooks.databinding.FragmentBooktitlesBinding

class BookTitle : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener { 

    private var _binding: FragmentBooktitlesBinding? = null

    private val binding get() = _binding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Book's implementation
        //val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_booktitles, container, false)
        //return view 
        _binding = FragmentBooktitlesBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding?.root
        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        view.rlas3.setOnClickListener(this) //the uresolved reference

    }

    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

I'm stuck with this issue in the compiler `Unresolved reference: rlas3`. 
I checked the layout's name: `fragment_booktitles.xml`, I checked the views' ids in this layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 ...
 <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    ...
         <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rlas3"
            ...
         <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rlas3kotlin"
            ...
         <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rminandroid"
```

How to get the reference according to the rule book because "View binding has important advantages over using `findViewById`" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```kotlin
package com.example.ch14fragmentsbooks

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.example.ch14fragmentsbooks.databinding.FragmentBooktitlesBinding

class BookTitle : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener { 

    private var _binding: FragmentBooktitlesBinding? = null

    private val binding get() = _binding!! // added !! 

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Book's implementation
        //val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_booktitles, container, false)
        //return view 
        _binding = FragmentBooktitlesBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root
        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        binding.rlas3.setOnClickListener(this) { // react on button click }// use the binding variable here

    }

    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

A bit of an explanation:

I added the `!!` to make the rest of your code easier to write (you don't have to write binding?.rlas3?.setOnClickListener(...)

Comment: Few questions: what's the purpose to use `view` as parameter of methods, to return it, if I access through binding ? `!!` makes it easier but does it make the code safer ? Using nullable receiver: `?` and not null assertion operator: `!!` seems contradictory even if the compiler accepts this.

Comment: 1. viewBinding was created years after the first android apps were created, a lot of code still requires views to be passed in / returned by certain functions in order to inflate / build 'stuff' properly, technically rewritting all of the code to use bindings of some sort would be possible, but it would probably take a lot of time + require a lot of attention regarding the memory leaks caused by the binding variables. Also, you could use the views to interact with buttons or other views that belong to a certain fragment, but that requires additional code (findViewById etc.)

Comment: 2. The `!!` will never cause a NullPointerException (if you do all the stuff binding requires (mainly the inflating part) correctly) in case of the binding variable, cause it is only valid between onCreateView and onDestroyView. (quote from the documentation page you referenced), not adding it would just make you type additional code (which would achieve the same result)

Comment: 3. just a tip, look in the documentation what happens with the binding variable inside `onDestoryView` (you NEED to add `_binding = null` in fragments to prevent memory leaks!)

Answer (score -1):

yeah, but if you want to solve this problem, you need to use the binding object to get a reference to the radiogroup and radiobutton views, with something like this:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

binding?.radioGroup?.findViewById<RadioButton>(R.id.rlas3)?.setOnClickListener(this)
binding?.radioGroup?.findViewById<RadioButton>(R.id.rlas3kotlin)?.setOnClickListener(this)
binding?.radioGroup?.findViewById<RadioButton>(R.id.rminandroid)?.setOnClickListener(this)
```

}

Comment: That's... not how you should use view binding

Comment: Binding (with `buildFeatures { viewBinding true}` written in `build.gradle`) is a way to avoid `findViewById` as said in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#findviewbyid) for "Null Safety, Type Safety, Faster Compilation, Ease of use".